# What is the vector in pointer means?

Tags: c++

When I was learning polimorphism, I'd seen a code like this:

```
Class A {};

int foo(vector<A*> &s){....}
```

what is the mean of `vector<A*>` and what is the mean of `vector<A*> &s` and how can I used foo fuction? For example

```
vector<A> a;
vector<A> b;
vector<A*> p;
p[0]=&a; //Why this is illegal?
```

and

```
foo(p); //Why this is illegal?
```

and my last quistion is,

what is the deference between `vector<A>`,`vector<A*>`,`vector<A>*`,`vector<vector<A>>` and `vector<vector<*A>>`

Comment: Don't think this is down vote worthy guys.  Honest question on usage here.

Comment: I think the question lacks research. There are plenty of resources explaining: what is a `vector` (in the context of `std`), or when and how to use it.
The "why is this illegal" part might be an okay question on their own, but if there was more research involved the question probably wouldn't be there

Comment: It the fundamental question on what is a type, as soon as Furkan learns this his life will be more complicated.

Comment: A vector is a container that can contain a variable number of items (including other vectors) which allows random access in constant time, among other features.    `Vector<A>` is a vector containing A classes.  The next is a vector containing pointers to A classes, the next is garbage without further info, the next is a vector than contains vectors or A classes.  The last is a vector than contains vectors of pointers to A classes.

Comment: Michael Dorgan thanks but I need a some example, using Vector<A*> ,Vector<A*>& and using foo fuction.

Comment: `foo(p); //Why this is illegal?` It isn't. See here: http://ideone.com/COrqE0

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confused about what type is decorated here. I'll start by explaining "what is a decorated type?"

The answer is this: A decorated type in C++ is a type that is transformed by additional symbol. It transform a type into another type. Let's make an example:

```
// The type of a is `int`. The type `int` is not decorated.
int a;

// The type of `b` is lvalue reference of int.
// We decorated int with a `&` to mean that it's a reference to int.
int& b = a;

// The type of `c` is lvalue reference to constant int.
// We decorated `int` with `const&` to mean that it's a reference to int, but constant.
int const& c = a;

// The type of `d` is pointer to int.
// We decorated the type `int` with the `*` to mean that it's a pointer to int.
int* d = &a;
//       ^--- be careful here, the & in front of a variable does
//            not mean it's a reference. We are not decorating a type here,
//            The `&` operator is used to get the address of a variable.
```

Okay, now that you know how types are decorated, let's see what the angle braket means. You see, `std::vector` is not a class. However, `std::vector<int>` is. You can't say "I want a list!" you have to say "I want a list of <`that`>".

You must put a type inside the angle brackets. In your case, the type is `A*`. `A` is a class, and `A*` is a decorated type that mean "a pointer to `A`". That means that the vector you have is a list of pointer to `A`!

Now that you know what the vector with the `A*` means, reading your function declaration is easy:

```
int foo(vector<A*>& s){....}
```

The type of `s` is a decoratede type. It's a reference of a vector. But wait, it's a reference of a vector that contains some `A*`. And `A*` is the type `A` decorated with the `*`, and that means it's a pointer to `A`. So here we have a reference of a vector of pointer to `A`.

---

> `p[0] = &a;` Why this is illegal?

To explain why, we must break the expression in parts.

```
    p   [0] = &a
// (1)  (2)   (3)
```

There is three parts. The first part is `p`. What is `p`? It's a vector of `A*`, just like before. No big deal.

Now what does the part `(2)` means? That's a call to the operator `[]` of `vector`. A vector is a list. The `[]` means we want to access to a particular element of the list. More specifically, we want to access the element at position `0`, hence the `[0]`. So you could see the whole expression as the first `A*` of the vector. That mean that `p[0]` **is** an `A*`.

Let's look at your expression again:

```
      p[0]   =   &a
 // first A* =   (3)
```

What is `&a`? If you remember in the first example, the `&` here means that we take the address of the variable `a`.

The type of an address is a pointer. So, the whole `&a` expression is of type of `vector<A>*`. I think now you now your mistake. Does it make sense to say this?

```
         p[0]      =         &a
 //     an A*      = a pointer to a vector of A
```

---

So now. How do you use the function `foo`?

You see, the function `foo` need a reference to a vector of pointer to A. If you remember the first example:

```
           int& b           =        a;
//  a reference to an int   =  an int variable
```

Reference to vector works in the same way:

```
          std::vector<A*>& b           =           a;
//  a reference to an vector<A*>       =  a vector<A*> variable
```

So for your function to work, you must send it what it ask: a vector to pointer to A.

```
std::vector<A*> a;

foo(a);
```

---

One last tip here: Get yourself a good C++ book. You can find all these things in book and online resources. You are less likely to find someone like me again that is willing to take his time to help you than finding a good book that explain it all.

Comment: Ohh thanks for helping but could you please give me some example about using "vector<A*>" and "vector<A*>&" and using foo function?

and another ı never understand question is that, what is the difference between address operator and referans?

Comment: @FurkanYıldız Short of writing a text book chapter, I don't see how much more he could help you. You should brush up your understanding of the language fundamentals. The following link may help: https://isocpp.org/images/uploads/2-Tour-Basics.pdf

Comment: @FurkanYıldız I added the explanation. Please read it carefully, especially the part that talks about getting a good C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

They are just sequence containers that represent arrays. They can be changed in size. When you use foo. foo is just a name that you use in examples where an identifier is required. But you have no context to give the identifier a name that is meaningful.

Comment: Can you explain better and can you give me any example?

Answer (score -1):

vector is a standard template library(STL). It's an array like container with dynamic size. You don't need to declare the size like array. It's complexity is as like as an array.

Comment: This does not appear to answer any of his questions.

Comment: STL was absorbed into the standard library decades ago. Let it die.

Comment: he also asked "what is the mean of "vector"?"

Comment: Ok, I see.  I missed that part.  My bad.

Comment: Michael Dorgan, thanks u are right, I did not write "what is the mean of "vector"?" , someone change my question.

I edided again and there is no answer for my any quistion.

Comment: Oh, but that wasn't my fault :)